# Call stored procedure from SSIS Dataflow

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

The question in short:
Can I call a stored procedure that has an output parameter in a data flow?

In long: 
I have many tables to extract, transform, and load from one db to another one.
Almost all of the tables require one transformation which is fixing the country codes (from 3 letters to two).  So my idea is as follows:
for each row: call the stored procedure, pass the wrong country code, replace the wrong code with the correct one (the output of the stored procedure)

Comment: The way I would do this is put the data in a staging table and perform a bulk update. If you don't want to do that you could use a lookup component. Why is the transformation in a stored procedure? Can't it be a simple lookup?

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two solutions for this:

- Look-Up component: configuring it in advance mode and make sure the last sentence of the SProc is the Select statement that returns the good country code (e.g. SELECT @good_country_code)
- Using an OLEDB Command

The latter (OLEDB Command) is actually quite simple, you need to configure it with:

```
EXEC ? = dbo.StoredProc @param1 = ?, @param2 = ?
```

As a consequence a @RETURN_VALUE will appear on the Available Destination Columns which you can then map to an existing column in the pipeline. Remember to create a new pipeline field/column (e.g. Good_Country_Code) using a Derived Column component before the OLEDB component and you'll have the chance to have both values, or replace the wrong one using another Derived Column component after OLEDB Command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found OLE DB command useful when for certain edge cases where I need to call a SP. This link - http://goo.gl/KefX0N gives a detailed explanation.

Comment: Good explanation under that link Karthik

Answer (score 3):

No, natively there isn't a component that is going to handle that. You can accomplish it with a Script Component but you don't want to.

What you're describing is a Lookup. The Data Flow Task has a Lookup Component but you'll be better served, especially for a finite list of values like Countries to push your query into the component.

SELECT T.Country3, T.Country2 FROM dbo.Table T;

Then you drag your SourceCountry column and match to Country3. Check Country2 and for all the rows that match, you'll get the 2 letter abbreviation.

A big disadvantage of trying to use your stored procedure is efficiency. The default Lookup is going to cache all those values. With the Script Version, say you have 10k rows come through, all with `CAN`. That's 10k invocations of your stored procedure where the results never change.

You do pay a startup cost as the default Lookup mode is Full Cache which means it's going to run your query and keep all those values local. This is great with your data set: 1000 countries max, 5 or 10 byte per row. That's nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You'll want to use a couple Execute SQL Tasks to do this.

1. Use an Execute SQL Task to gather a Result Set of `Wrong_Country_Code`s.
2. Add a ForEach Container as a successor to the previous Execute SQL Task. Pass the Result Set to this Container.
3. Inside that ForEach container, you will have another Execute SQL Task that will call your sproc, using each row (e.g. `Wrong_Country_Code`) as a variable parameter.

That should work. Only select the columns necessary to pass to your stored procedure.

**Edit**

In acknowledgement to the other answer, performance is going to be an issue. Perhaps rather than have the stored procedure produce an output, alter the sproc to do the updates for you.

Comment: As @billinkc notes, there is an efficiency cost here that should be noted.

Comment: That's very true, I've added an edit. @billinkc is right about a native component, my answer is more of a cobbled-together solution that should work, with a few important considerations.